# Tried to open VSCode with subprocess module in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, subprocess

[CMD writes this when I run command "vsc" which open VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3fL4.png)

This is the function i made to open VSCode

```
def openVSC():
    subprocess.call(["C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe"])
```

And this is the code that calls the function "openVSC()"

```
while True:

    command_input = input(prompt).lower()


    if command_input == "open spotify":
        print("Opening Spotify...")
        openSpotify()
        print()

    elif command_input == "www":
        print("Opening Google Chrome...")
        openChrome()
        print()

    elif command_input == "vsc":
        print("Opening VSCode...")
        openVSC()
        print()


    elif command_input == "quit":
        break

    else:
        pass
```

Also when I close the cmd VSCode also closes so I was thinking that the CMD was running VSCode on his own... Nothing seems to work and i tried about everything.

Comment: You should copy/paste or write out the error you're getting, rather than linking to a picture. Please use the [edit] link to add this information to your question. Also, there's no clear question in your "question", only a description of what's happening. What do you expect should happen that's not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very vague, more information would be appreciated. Assuming you issue is that you are only getting STDOUT from the vscode call, thats because you are using call(), which waits for the process to complete before returning control to your program. Use something like this to make your call, and you can set where STDOUT points to as to read output whilst using the program being called by your script.

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT
import os

Popen(['vscode'], stdout=os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR), stderr=STDOUT)
```

This will open the process to run as a child and your program will wait for the child to terminate at this point. Read more into subprocess and this should all make more sense. hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! very fast response and it worked, I will also check out the link to the subprocess doc, have a good day!

Comment: Of course, I always rush into new libraries myself! Enjoy :)

Comment: if I hit Win+R, and type `code` it opens, but if I do `subprocess.run('code')` it fails?